# Webpack running through grunt webpack doesn't error or complete, or do anything

Tags: angularjs, webpack, gruntjs

Trying to convert an old system off bower into npm using webpack, and grunt webpack. Just trying to use webpack to load in NPM files, not run anything else, and the rest of the grunt file finishes loading and uglifying and stuff, and runs its own node server. It gets to this point and freezes and never comes back.

```
Loading "grunt-webpack" plugin

Registering "/Users/***/***/***/node_modules/grunt-webpack/tasks" tasks.
Loading "webpack-dev-server.js" tasks...OK
+ webpack-dev-server
Loading "webpack.js" tasks...OK
+ webpack

Running "webpack" task
```

Here's my grunt code (super basic obviously)

```
webpack: {
  options: require("./config/webpack.dev.js"),
},
```

Here's that dev file

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const helpers = require('./helpers');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { BaseHrefWebpackPlugin } = require('base-href-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ConcatPlugin = require('webpack-concat-plugin');
const ngInventory = require('./ng1-vendor-index.js');

const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'dev';

module.exports = merge(common(ENV), {
    devtool: 'source-map',

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|js)$/,
                loaders: ['angular-router-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.((s*)css)$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'style-loader',
                },{
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                },{
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /src\/.+\.(ts|js)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|\.spec\.ts$)/,
                loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
                enforce: 'post',
                options: {
                    esModules: true
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    debug: true,
    devTool: 'eval',
    plugins: [
        new ConcatPlugin({
            uglify: false,
            sourceMap: true,
            name: 'vendor',
            outputPath: './',
            fileName: '[name].[hash].js',
            filesToConcat: ngInventory.vendor1
        }),

        new BaseHrefWebpackPlugin({ baseHref: '/'}),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            favicon: helpers.root('client/assets/image/favicon.png'),
            template: "./client/index.html",
            filename: "./client/index.html",
        }),
       new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    ],
});
```

And here is the common file:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
const helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = env => ({
    entry: {
        server: './server/app.js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: helpers.root(`dist/${env}`),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: '[name].js'
    },
    target: 'node',
    node: {
        // Need this when working with express, otherwise the build fails
        __dirname: false,   // if you don't put this is, __dirname
        __filename: false,  // and __filename return blank or /
    },
    externals: [nodeExternals()],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
            // Transpiles ES6-8 into ES5
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                  loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                include: [
                    helpers.root('client'),
                ],
                loader: 'html-loader'
            },

            {
                test: /\.((s*)css)%/,
                include: [
                    helpers.root('client/app'),
                    helpers.root('client/components'),
                ],
                exclude: 'node_modules/',
                loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            },

            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|tts)$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader'
                }]
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [

        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'ENV': JSON.stringify(env)
            }
        }),

        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)esm5/, path.join(__dirname, './client')),
    ]
});
```

A sample from the vendor index file:

```
const helper = require('./helpers');

exports.vendor1 = [
    helper.root('node_modules/lodash/lodash.js'),
    helper.root('node_modules/lodash-deep/lodash-deep.js'),
...
...
]
```

I'm just really not sure what to do, couldn't bring up any google results or stack results because theres no errors happening either. I've tried all verbose levels of logging all to no avail. What in the world am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-webpack) shows, you haven't configured any targets, like `dev` or `prod`. You've only specified `options`. You want

```
webpack: {
  options: {},
  dev: require("./config/webpack.dev.js"),
},
```

As an aside, there's no benefit to using Webpack with Grunt.

Comment: Sweet baby Jesus if that's what I've missed, I may run into a wall headfirst. Yeah all I'm trying to do is write the new components into the index file from npm instead of bower. This might be over-engineering. Might be the easiest 100 rep you've made friend.